# Explanation of fill_diagonal syntax

Tags: python, numpy, diagonal

I'm having trouble understanding how np.fill_diagonal is implemented here.

I found a post [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2017-January/076388.html) explaining a way to fill the sub and super diagonals with certain values but I don't really understand the arguments of the function. Here is the code:

```
a = np.zeros((4, 4))
b = np.ones(3)
np.fill_diagonal(a[1:], b)
np.fill_diagonal(a[:,1:], -b)
```

I don't understand how fill_diagonal is used here. I thought that the second argument had to be a [scalar](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html). Also, I don't understand what is happening with the slices of 'a'.

Answer (score 1):

"For an array a with `a.ndim >= 2`, the diagonal is the list of locations with indices `a[i, ..., i]` all identical. This function modifies the input array in-place, it does not return a value." ([Source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html)) The documentation for this method says `b` should be a scalar, however if `b` is an array of length equal to the length of the diagonal of the input array, then it will fill the values of `b` in for the diagonal.

The key is that the number of elements in `b` is equal to the number of elements along the diagonals of each sub-array of `a`. The *n*th diagonal value of the sub-array is filled in with the *n*th value of `b`.

The first sub-array of `a` that is modified is all but the first row of `a` (this means 3 rows, 4 columns), so the number of diagonal elements is 3.

The second sub-array of `a` is the last three columns (4 x 3 matrix) of `a` which also has only 3 diagonal elements.

==========================================================================
Thanks G. Anderson for the comment. I'm editing this into the post to draw attention to it:

"It's worth noting that b doesn't have to have the same length as the diagonal it's filling. if b is longer, then n elements of the diagonal will be filled with the first n elements of b. If n is shorter than the diagonal, then b will be repeated to fill the diagonal"

Comment: It's worth noting that `b` doesn't _have to have the same length_ as the diagonal it's filling. if `b` is longer, then `n` elements of the diagonal will be filled with the first `n` elements of b. If `n` is shorter than the diagonal, then `b` will be repeated to fill the diagonal

Answer (score 0):

Your examples involve filling slices, `views`, of the original array.

```
In [79]: a = np.zeros((4, 4)) 
    ...: b = np.arange(1,5)                                                                                  
In [80]:
```

The simple case - filling the whole array:

```
In [80]: np.fill_diagonal(a,b)                                                                               
In [81]: a                                                                                                   
Out[81]: 
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 4.]])
```

`fill_diagonal` takes an array to be filled, and values to put in the diagonal.  The docs does say `scalar`, but that's overly restrictive.  As I show, it can be a 1d array of the right size.

```
In [82]: a = np.zeros((4, 4)) 
    ...: b = np.arange(1,4)
```

filling the last 3 rows:

```
In [83]: a[1:]                                                                                               
Out[83]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
In [84]: np.fill_diagonal(a[1:],b)                                                                           
In [85]: a                                                                                                   
Out[85]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3., 0.]])

In [86]: a = np.zeros((4, 4)) 
    ...: b = np.arange(1,4)
```

filling the last 3 columns:

```
In [87]: a[:,1:]                                                                                             
Out[87]: 
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
In [88]: np.fill_diagonal(a[:,1:],b)                                                                         
In [89]: a                                                                                                   
Out[89]: 
array([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 3.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

The key is that `fill_diagonal` works in-place, and the `a[1:]` and `a[:,1:]` produce views of `a`.

Look at the slice of `a` after filling:

```
In [90]: a[:,1:]                                                                                             
Out[90]: 
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

The docs demonstrate the use with `np.fliplr(a)`.  That too, creates a `view` which can be modified in place.

The actual write is done with:

```
a.flat[:end:step] = val
```

where `end` and `step` have been calculated from the dimensions.  For example to fill a 3x3 array, we can write to every 4th element.

```
In [96]: a[:,1:].ravel()                                                                                     
Out[96]: array([1., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 3., 0., 0., 0.])
```